Should the copper pouring be done before starting to route traces in PCB design?
Is there any rule or convention about the order of pouring copper such as ground planes before starting to route traces or the other way around?
What is the order for these two steps in PCB design in general when using a CAD program?

Placing power/ground planes and large polygon sections typically gets rid of a lot of airwires so I tend to do them early on as it removes a lot of clutter...

I think it's better to hide the nets (and their rubber band lines) that are going to be joined by pours, and shelve the pours while doing the layout, maybe bringing them back periodically to see what's up.
You do usually want to keep an eye on what the routing is doing to the pours, so it's really not an either-or thing- it's interactive and usually iterative. You also have to leave enough room for vias to a ground pour during the routing, for example, but I think it's easier to leave that to later if you have an idea of the space required for each.
If you're splitting a plane to route various power domains this had better be part of the placement process to make sure the nets that correspond to each power rail are grouped as nicely as makes sense.
In general, placement is underrated and (last I looked anyway) computers are not excellent at it.
Professional layout folks may have a different approach, but this works for me.

There are no rules - you do what you think is best for your PCB design.
Usually the most important traces are done first, so if you think the ground plane is the most important thing then you might want to do it first. Generally, that is not the case, but it also depends on what you are doing and if the ground fill is even important for what you are doing, and how many PCB layers you got.
For example in a 4 layer PCB, you might want to do the ground plane on layer 2 or 3 first if you intend to use the plane as reference for impedance controlled signals.
